# Clojure list (seq) traversal to compare items to other items

Tags: clojure

Say I have a list (a b c d e), I'm trying to figure out a "lazy" and Clojure-idiomatic way of producing a list or seq of each item with each other item, such as ((a b) (a c) (a d) (a e) (b c) (b d) (b e) (c d) (c e) (d e)).

Clojure's for doesn't seem to allow this, it just produces one item as it goes through a list and doesn't allow access to a sub-list. The closest I've come so far is to turn the original list into a vector, and have a for statement that iterates over the count of the vector and grab indexed items,

> (for [i (range vector-count) j (range i vector-count)]
>   ...

but I hope that there's a better way.

Comment: ok, there's a better way. To help others who find this, I used clojure.contrib.combinatorics, (combinations '(a b c d e) 2)

Answer (score 3):

You want combinations.  There's a function to give you a lazy sequence of combinations [right here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib/blob/master/modules/combinatorics/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/combinatorics.clj) in clojure-contrib.

```
user> (combinations [:a :b :c :d :e] 2)
((:a :b) (:a :c) (:a :d) (:a :e) (:b :c) (:b :d) (:b :e) (:c :d) (:c :e) (:d :e))
```

(Unfortunately, the monolithic clojure-contrib repo containing that file is deprecated in favor of splitting contrib up into smaller separate repos, and `clojure.contrib.combinatorics` doesn't seem to have made the transition yet, so there's no easy way currently to install that library, but you can snag the code from github if nothing else.)

Comment: This is now packaged as [`clojure/math.combinatorics`](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics).

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I tried writing this without looking at the code in contrib. I think my code is much easier to understand, and in my simple-minded benchmark it's more than twice as fast. It's available at https://gist.github.com/1042047, and reproduced below for convenience:

```
(defn combinations [n coll]
  (if (= 1 n)
    (map list coll)
    (lazy-seq
     (when-let [[head & tail] (seq coll)]
       (concat (for [x (combinations (dec n) tail)]
                 (cons head x))
               (combinations n tail))))))

user> (require '[clojure.contrib.combinatorics :as combine])
nil
user> (time (last (user/combinations 4 (range 100))))
"Elapsed time: 4379.959957 msecs"
(96 97 98 99)
user> (time (last (combine/combinations (range 100) 4)))
"Elapsed time: 10913.170605 msecs"
(96 97 98 99)
```

I strongly prefer the [n coll] argument order, rather than [coll n] - clojure likes the "important" argument to come last, especially for functions dealing with seqs: mostly this is for ease of combination with `(->>)` in scenarios like `(->> (my-list) (filter even?) (take 10) (combinations 8))`.

Comment: +1 for a great solution. On the argument order, my understanding of preferred style is that sequences should always be the last argument, but if you are dealing with a single main object then it should be the first argument. See: http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/8b2c8dc96b39ddd7/a8866d34b601ff43 for some explanation

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the pointer. If nothing else, I'm tickled pink to read about a time when Stuart Sierra was astonished that sets were callable!

Answer (score 1):

why use range and index grabbing in the for loop?

```
(let [myseq (list :a :b :c :d)]
    (for [a myseq b myseq] (list a b)))
```

works.

Comment: No good. It includes `(:a :a)` in the result. It's also easier to write this as `(map list myseq myseq)`.

Comment: `(for [x myseq y myseq :when (not= x y)] [x y])`

Comment: @amalloy No. The `for` is not equivalent to your `map`.

Comment: But you do include `(:a :b)` as well as `(:b :a)`, which I don't think he wants.

Comment: amalloy is correct, I needed only one of `(:a :b)` and `(:b :a)`